# Rails assets not available on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

I have this specific issue. On a (LARGE) rails setup I have a backbone project in `/app/assets/reader/`. All of my javascript assets are precompiling dynamically into `reader.js`, this works fine. My i10n files in `locale/` don't play nice however because they don't need any precompiling. In development it works fine, but in production they are not available.

In my `/app/views/layouts/reader.html.erb` file I have the following lines:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "reader" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "locale/en" %>
```

The problem is that the lower one results in a 404 error on production.

I've tried the following alternatives:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "en" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "locale/en" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "reader/locale/en" %>
```

None of these seem work. The last one even broke on development.

PS: in `applicaton.rb` I have:

```
...
config.assets.precompile += [
    ...
    'reader.js',
    ...
]
...
config.assets.paths << File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'reader', 'locale')
```

Comment: Remove cached files in the public directory then recompile your files and it should work for both the development and production.

Comment: Done, an awful lot of times. Still no joy.

Comment: Solved it! `'locale/*.js',` was missing from the `config.assets.precompile` array in `application.rb`.

Comment: can you mark my answer below since I've help solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not in the `javascript_include_tag`, but rather in the way `config.assets.precompile` was formatted.

By default Rails scans for any subfolder DIRECTLY within `assets`. That meant that the locale file had to be added as `locale/en.js` to `config.assets.precompile`, and that the `config.assets.paths` line was not even necessary at all.

The way rails scans subfolder is really specific and important. Get that right, and it should all work like a breeze. Once you know how it works, it actually gets quite powerful.

Pro tip:
I ended up using `locale/*.js` in combination with `<%= javascript_include_tag "locale/#{I18n.locale}" %>`, as I actually have a lot of locale files.

Answer (score 1):

You removed all files in public directory folder then restarted server? Also inside of your js folder you have a folder

> reader/locale/en.js

? Double check all paths and if it works in development you should check out your error log in production to see where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, turns out there is a line in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
```

which didn't allow Rails to serve static files, including the precompiled assets. Changing it to

```rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

fixes the issue.

This is caused by the fact that Nginx and Apache handle static serving on their own. But Rails is configured to use Puma by default so this doesn't really make too much sense for it to default to these settings.